# What is the closest tasting beer to Erdinger?

Tags: taste

I love Erdinger and wheat beers in general, after trying some of Erdginers others types I wondered what other beer out there is close to Erdinger taste

Comment: Erdinger is a brewery, not a specific beer. Are you talking about [this beer](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/erdinger-weissbier-hefe-weizen/2468/)?

Comment: Please specify what beer you are talking about. They have many.

Comment: In my opinion, there are much, much better wheat beers than Erdinger.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about the [Erdinger hefeweissbier](http://www.erdinger.de/en/erdinger-weissbier-products/beer/weissbier.html).  This is a good example of the beer style known as [German-style wheat beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_beer) / BJCP category 15A.

It also goes by the names: Weizen, Weissbier (Weißbier), Wheat beer, etc. etc.

Lots of German breweries produce great examples of this style of beer: Weihenstephan, Franziskaner, Schneider, Aying.  I believe that if you like Erdinger, many of these companies' wheat beers will be to your liking.

IMHO the closet to Erdinger Hefeweissbier would be from Franziskaner (obviously this is a very subjective assertion, YMMV).  It would be interesting to line some of these up for a taste-difference test.

But you may be able to find German-style wheat beers brewed in many other countries.  Do not be confused with an "American Style Wheat-beer" / BJCP Category 6D.  This is a significantly different sort of beer.

Given your liking of these sorts of beers, you might also enjoy Belgian style wheat beers, collectively known as Witbier.